# Flexi auth setting Role based access control

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using flexi auth for authentication in my site. I would like to add Role based access control to my site and I got to know that setting privileges is one of the options. But, currently I am not using any privilege tables. So I am confused on how to implement it in the current working site.

I would also like to grant multiple previlages for the same user. Eg: A single user can login as admin as well as a normal user.